# CSS Button with both Radius and Arrow, Possible?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a site where I need both of these styles on the same button. I need a radius on the left hand side with the right hand side being an arrow. I've tried a few things. example the old fashioned background image with it aligned right for the arrow. Adding the web-kit radius to the button which didn't work out to good.

In the past I'd create the button as a back ground image. But with CSS3 and a bit of magic I'm sure there's a much better way to achieve this?

Anyone got a cleaner solution to the problem? I've had a google with a few coffee's But nothing quite does what I'm trying to do.

-I'm using bootstrap 2.3 has a framework so this would need to work on as many browsers as possible and at multiscreen resolutions.

[image: IMAGE OF WHAT THE BUTTONS LOOK LIKE ON THE PSD.]

Comment: It might be, where are you stuck?

Comment: What have you actually tried before deciding to ask? It seems that you are simply waiting for us code monkeys to write you a solution... not gonna happen.

Comment: @Terry It seems it has just happened, by JoshC

Comment: Just on the cleanest way to do it that will support has many browsers as possible. My plan was to create the button with the radius then use a background image for the arrow and assign it to the right hand side.

Just wondering if there's a better way to do this ? I've worked out almost everything else on the site markup and style wise. Its just these two buttons.

Comment: @oriol Unfortunately, some decide to feed the lazies.

Comment: @Terry I thought it was a good question, so I answered it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible through usage of the `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VEGv7/) - Basic example

**HTML** - pretty simple

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

div:before {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid black;
    z-index: 10;
}

div:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Josh I will take everything you have created and have a play I was unware of :before and :after tags.  I knew there would be a much better way to do it than my solution. I will take what you have supplied and have a play.

@The the others no need to be so hostile. I'd done a bit of reading, bit of fiddling I didn't expect anyone to write my code. A simple have a read on :before and :after would of been enough. But Josh has been a star.

Comment: Ok guys after Josh set me off on the right track had a read up on the after and before pseudo classes. I got my head around how Josh created the button.

What would be the best way to create the double arrow. I see how Josh did the orignal with two triangles to create the illustion. Ive read up on after:after tag but it seems not all browsers support it on further investigation. Is there a better way to do the double arrow ? *second button.*

Is that one out teh question and I'd need to fall back to using an image?

Comment: Added the question above mate, if you dont mind me being a pain is it possible to create the white arrow like Ive shown with the red circle. heres an image of what I mean 
http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/6856/gvah.jpg

Heres my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/LWXFX/1/

Comment: If i have confused you basically is the double arrow possible like the grey button in the orignal image. I can see it can be done with :after:after but from what ive read this isnt a good web standard.

Also is it possible to run the arrow right out to the edge like circled in red ?

Comment: Any chance of some help Josh ?

Comment: @lees Well - since it takes 2 pseudo elements (both `before`/`after`) to create one arrow, you would actually need 3 in order to make both arrows, and an overlay. Since it is not possible to have multiple pseudo elements, you would actually need to make another element in the DOM to achieve this..

Comment: looks like for making white arrow to overlap main div we need additional element with white color, i will try to do and share my results

Answer (score 0):

I modified code above to achieve the goal you want: exactly the same as on your picture

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body  { 
   background: blue; 
}

#div1 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   background: black;
   position: relative;
   border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
   z-index: 9;
}

#div1:before {
   content: '\A';
   position: absolute;
   right: -28px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 25px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
   border-left: 30px solid black;
   z-index: 10;
}

#div1:after {
   content: '\A';
   position: absolute;
   right: -38px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 25px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
   border-left: 30px solid white;
}

#div2 {
   width: 20px;
   height: 50px;
   background: white;
   left: 196;
   top: 8;
   position: absolute;
}
```